# How to separate employee value rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert Employee records  rows to automatic  columns in SQL Server, I heard that PIVOT is not very fast, and I need to deal with lot of records.

I have data records like this below

```
EmployeeNumber  Employee Name       Account Number
--------------------------------------------------
100204          Brody, David        4125641146
100204          Brody, David        5300880081

100239          Moland, Luke        34901876
100239          Moland, Luke        0441360299
```

This is my result: employees have multiple account numbers, I want look like my data

```
  EmployeeNumber    Employee Name   AccountNumber  AccountNumber1
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
   100204           Brody, David      4125641146    5300880081
   100239           Moland, Luke      34901876      0441360299
```

How can I build the result? Can anyone please help me to get my result ?

Comment: How many account numbers can an employee have? Is there a maximum?

Comment: maxium 4  account number

Comment: Then you can edit the answer below from @fa06 for `rn=3` and `rn=4` also allowing for `null` conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below way

```
select EmployeeNumber,EmployeeName,
max(case when rn=1 then AccountNumber end) as  AccountNumber  ,
max(case when rn=2 then AccountNumber end) as  AccountNumber1
from
(
select EmployeeNumber,  EmployeeName,   AccountNumber,row_number() over(partition by EmployeeName order by AccountNumber) as rn
from tablename
)A group by EmployeeNumber,EmployeeName
```

Comment: i am getting error Incorrect syntax near 'parition'.